# Tangent Map of an Isometry and the Shape Operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, isometry, tangent-bundle

I have spent a lot of time on this problem and would appreciate some help. Please bear with me.

> Let $M$ be a surface and $F\colon\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ an isometry. Denote with $F_\ast$ the tangent map of $F$. Let $U$ be a unit normal vector field on $\mathcal{V}\subset M$ and let $\overline{U}=F_\ast U$ be the unit normal vector field on $F(\mathcal{V})$. Let $S$ be the shape operator on $M$ determined by $U$ and $\overline{S}$ the shape operator of $F(M)$ determined by $\overline{U}$. Let $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$. Show that $$F_\ast S_p(v_p)=\overline{S}_{F(p)}(F_\ast v_p).$$

Here is my attempt. First the left-hand side: the shape operator $S$ acting on a tangent vector $v_p$ is the covariant derivative of $U$ at $p$ in the direction of $v$. So if $\alpha$ is a curve such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=v_p$ then 
$$S_p(v_p) =-\nabla_{v_p}U = \frac{d}{dt}U(\alpha(t))\big|_{t=0}.$$
If we call $U'\colon\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ the map that sends points to the vector part of $U$ (that is, ignoring the base point) then
$$S_p(v_p) = -DU'(\alpha(0))\alpha'(0) ~\text{ at } p =J_{U'}(p)v ~\text{ at } p,$$
where $DU'$ is the derivative of $U'$ which is also the Jacobian matrix $J_{U'}$. Next, the tangent map $F_\ast$ sends tangent vectors $v_p$ to tangent vectors $J_F(p)v$ at $F(p)$. Then
$$F_\ast S_p(v_p) = F_\ast\left(-J_{U'}(p)v ~\text{ at } p\right) = -J_F(p)J_{U'}(p)v ~\text{ at } F(p).$$
Now for the right-hand side: the shape operator $\overline{S}$ acting on a tangent vector $w_q$ is the covariant derivative of $\overline{U}$ at $q$ in the direction of $w$. Following our steps above,
$$ \overline{S}_q(w_q) = -D\overline{U}'(q)w ~\text{ at } q.$$
Since $F_\ast v_p$ is $J_F(p)v$ at $F(p)$, we have
$$ \overline{S}_{F(p)}(F_\ast v_p) = -D\overline{U}'(F(p))J_F(p)v ~\text{ at } F(p).$$
But what is $\overline{U}'$? By definition $\overline{U}=F_\ast U$, so at every point $p\in M$, $\overline{U}(p)=F_\ast U(p) = J_F(p)U'(p)$ at $F(p)$. So we can say $F_\ast U$ is the function $p\mapsto J_F(p)U'(p)$. Then
$$\overline{S}_{F(p)}(F_\ast v_p) = -D\big(J_FU'\big)(F(p))J_F(p)v ~\text{ at } F(p).$$
From here, I don't know how to relate the two sides to each other. Part of my trouble is all the varying notation, which may have caused a mistake above. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Hey, I'm currently stuck on a similar problem: I have an isometry $\phi$ between surfaces $M$ and $\tilde{M}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and want to show that $\phi_* L_p(e_i) = \tilde{L}_{\phi(p)}(\phi_* e_i)$ for an orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2$ of the tangent space of $M$. Did you ever end up finding a solution? (here $\phi_* : T_p M \to T_{\phi(p)} \tilde{M}$ denotes the differential of $\phi$)

Comment: @SV-97 unfortunately I never did find a solution to this. Yours seems like a generalization of mine, where $L$ is any linear map between the tangent spaces, rather than just the shape operator. But can you just clear up how $\tilde{L}$ is related to $L$? That might be important. For example in my problem, the shape operator $\overline{S}$ is related to $S$ through the unit normal vector fields $U$ and $F_* U$.

Comment: Ah that's sad :/ But I thought yours was more general actually since you have the equality for all $v_p$ whereas I only require it for an orthogonal basis (okay it's not that much more general since $L$ is linear but still). $L$ is also the shape operator in my case (arguably $S$ makes more sense though; I'm following Tu's "Differential geometry" and he uses $L$ for some reason). So the shape operators should be related in the same way as in your problem. I have made some progress since yesterday I think:

Comment: If we consider the situation in local coordinates the equation in question is equivalent to $J L_p(e_i) = \tilde{L}_{\phi(p)}(J e_i)$ where J is the Jacobian of $\phi$. At this point the equality if definitely true (it's listed for example in the table here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#First_and_second_fundamental_forms,_the_shape_operator,_and_the_curvature). I think to prove it we can consider the transformation matrix of the shape operator in this equation and apply the chain rule? I haven't tried it in detail but I think that'd work.